# Is there possibility to resize the image programmatic by click on button?

Tags: android

I am initially showing an empty view. When I click on the "Add Image" button it shows a group of images in a grid then I click on an image. I am placing image in the view by adding the ImageView dynamically using Drag Layer. In this way I am adding more Images. Now I want to resize each of the image programmatically. Is it possible? Please provide the code if it is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following code to resize an image. if you know the image path and required width and height

```
public static Bitmap resizeBitMapImage1(String filePath, int targetWidth,
            int targetHeight) {
        Bitmap bitMapImage = null;
        // First, get the dimensions of the image
        Options options = new Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        double sampleSize = 0;
        // Only scale if we need to
        // (16384 buffer for img processing)
        Boolean scaleByHeight = Math.abs(options.outHeight - targetHeight) >= Math
                .abs(options.outWidth - targetWidth);

        if (options.outHeight * options.outWidth * 2 >= 1638) {
            // Load, scaling to smallest power of 2 that'll get it <= desired
            // dimensions
            sampleSize = scaleByHeight ? options.outHeight / targetHeight
                    : options.outWidth / targetWidth;
            sampleSize = (int) Math.pow(2d,
                    Math.floor(Math.log(sampleSize) / Math.log(2d)));
        }

        // Do the actual decoding
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[128];
        while (true) {
            try {
                options.inSampleSize = (int) sampleSize;
                bitMapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

                break;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                try {
                    sampleSize = sampleSize * 2;
                } catch (Exception ex1) {

                }
            }
        }

        return bitMapImage;
    }
```

Thanks
Deepak