# Change image size without stretching

Tags: android, android-imageview, scale, android-image, aspect-ratio

This is the image which i getting from server.[image]

This is my resized image.
[image]

My `ImageView` height is always `120dp` and width is `fill_parent`. I am getting 1024*1024 px images from server. How can i change the image for setting in my `ImageView` without stretching? I have worked out [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381780/is-there-possibility-to-resize-the-image-programmatic-by-click-on-button),[two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312414/java-android-working-with-image-scaling-cropping-programmatically),[three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232608/fit-image-into-imageview-keep-aspect-ratio-and-then-resize-imageview-to-image-d),etc. But i got stretchable image.
Give some idea to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reduce the sample size while decoding the image.

Comment: I tried this. I can't get

Answer (score 0):

In the XML you could try using:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="120dp"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```